# nameserver problem for internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dns

I installed `ubuntu 16.04` on a HP labtop. Right now, I can get access to wifi. For instance, `ping 104.16.33.249` will return as

```
PING stackoverflow.com (104.16.33.249) 56(84) bytes of data
64 bytes from 104.16.33.249: icmp_seq=9  ttl=55  time=196 ms
```

However, when opening "stackoverflow.com" from firefox browser, the firefox returns as "server not found". Moreover, when trying to `ping stackoverflow.com`, the return is `ping: unknown host stackoverflow.com`. May I know how to solve it. After searching different forums, looks like I need to change the `/etc/resolv.conf`  This is the current output of this file,

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by      resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

But it does not solve this problem either. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have similar questions, waiting for answer as well.